# Problem in migrate magento 1.9 to 2

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

I want to migrate magento 1.9 to magento 2 for this I have install magento2 and use magento2-migration tool for migration.

But on the 5th step of migration `Migrate Products` it gives me `CDbException` because my magento site has above 30,000 products.

[image]

How to migrate products from magento 1.9 to magento 2?

Comment: are you on shared or dedicated server ?

Comment: Maybe better to use official tool for data migration?

Comment: I don't know about server. Is server effect migration process?

Comment: I have used migration tool provided by github https://github.com/ubertheme/magento2_data_migration/releases

Comment: try to use  : https://github.com/ubertheme/module-ubdatamigration